# Isomorphism between $O(2n,\mathbb{R})$ and $O(n,n,\mathbb{R})$ and same question for their Lie algbera

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, orthogonal-matrices

Is there any isomorphism of Lie groups between $O(2n,\mathbb{R})$ and $G:=\{ X \in M_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{R}) \mid X^tSX = S\} $ where $S$=$\begin{pmatrix}
  & {I_n}\\
I_n &   
\end{pmatrix}$.
 If not  , are their Lie algebras isomorphic ? What is an example of an isomorphism(s) ,if any?

Comment: No, $O(2n,\Bbb R)$ is compact, the other is not. Also their Lie algebras are not isomorphic. In general, it is a custom here to include some of your own thoughts/attempts into the question.

Comment: @Peter Franek Thanks! Compactness does the job for groups. I could just check the dimensions are same for groups as well as for Lie algebras and started trying to construct a Lie algebra isomorphism but failed.

Comment: They are not isomorphic, but that's somehow less trivial to see. There is a well-known correspondence between Lie algebras and simply connected Lie groups, and this correspondence assigns to $o(2n)$ a covering of $SO(2n)$, the Spin group, which is compact, but it assigns some non-compact covering of $SO(n,n)$ to $o(n,n)$. For a direct proof, I would try to show that $o(2n)$ does not contain a copy of $o(1,1)$ inside. Or to show that any Lie group with Lie algebra $o(n,n)$ is non-compact.

Comment: (An even simpler argument: compute the signatures of the Killing forms).

Comment: $\mathfrak{o}(2n)$ has the property that for every $g$ all eigenvalues of $ad(g)$ are purely imaginary, unlike $\mathfrak{o}(n,n)$.